# How should my controllers communicate with my services in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make my controllers thin, perfectly one service call. So I write my action:

```
public function actionDoSomething($request, $arg1, $arg2)
{
    $result = $someService->doSomething($arg1, $arg2);

    if ($result === true)
        return 'Done';

    return 'Failed, but cannot say why';
}
```

Now I have my doubts:

1. Is it fine that user input is passed directly to the service,
   without any sanitisation/filtering/validation? Maybe it's not always necessary to even call it (for example `$arg1` is expected to be integer but user entered 1.25)?
2. Service may do a lot of work controller doesn't know about. What type should be returned from the service? boolean, integer, SomeResult class, array, mixed? What data should be returned in case of fail? const value, array of messages? I need it for the response. Is there any standard or best practice I can adopt?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. The format of data you pass to the service layer should be driven by the service layer itself. You can have several kinds of UIs — HTML, REST, command line — each exchanging data with the user differently. All those kinds of controllers have to parse the user data and pass it to the service layer in the format it understands and vice versa — fetch the data from the service layer and format it according to the type of the UI.

   Final validation can be done in the service layer to make sure invalid data doesn't pass though it but you still can call the validation services from the controllers if that helps you to report validation errors to the user in a more friendly way.
2. The type of data the service layer returns depends on what a method you're calling is supposed to do. For example, a data saving method may return nothing, while a data fetching entity will return the data in the format you need or like.

   What you should *not* do is to check the success of an operation of a service method — or any other method — by the value it returns — PHP exceptions are for that. That is, assume that everything went smooth unless an exception has been thrown.

Comment: That's why you could run validation before passing data to a service. But if invalid data reaches a service, it is an exception.

Comment: So I have to validate the same data twice?

Comment: Well, it really depends. Sometimes just catching an exception from the service layer could be enough, but sometimes you might want to validate stuff before passing it to the service layer for some reason. It's up to you. BTW, you're validating data at least twice anyway — at least you should — once in the application and once in the database.

Comment: The point is my controller cannot be responsible for input validation, but needs to know somehow why operation failed (to show the message for the user), but on the other hand service layer shouldn't know about UI staff at all.

Comment: Why can't it? Well, the controller itself is not responsible for validation — it just delegates it to the validation facilities — by using the `validator` service, for example — and formats the returned constraint violation list according to the UI being used.